# Eclipse Pydev - Misdiplayed Import Error

Tags: python, eclipse, import

I have been haunted by a 'trivial problem' for a while. I just installed PIL package and I have no problem importing it and using it both from my command line python and eclipse python. And I used sys.path to check they have almost exactly the same path. However, In eclipse, it always shows the red error dot on the screen that there is something wrong with the library 'unresolved import', which is absolutely nonsense. I could run the code and see the expected output which means that the module has been imported successfully!

I am wondering has this happened to any of you guys. I could move on with my work but.. it is just super annoying working on something that always shows 'Error'. Screen shot is attached just for your information.

[image]

Comment: Have you imported the library to your interpreter?

Comment: I cannot see the logic ... I can use the library, but it tells me unresolved import? btw, in the path for PIL has been added to my python interpreter path... I also tried to add it by go to the property of my python project and added PIL also as external library..

Comment: So when you go to: Window -> Preferences -> PyDev -> Interpreter - Python, you have the path of PIL added to your library for the current version you use? - If so I'm not sure. Adding libraries like that fixed it for me (not with PIL in particularly though).

Comment: I do have the path for PIL in the place you just described.... Still no luck

Comment: http://www.mail-archive.com/pydev-code@lists.sourceforge.net/msg00678.html - Seems like an old problem that is still not fixed :-(

Comment: Good to know, thanks for looking into that. It is what it is...