# Eclipse error "warning" not going away

Tags: python, eclipse, import

I'm using Eclipse (on the PyDev perspective), and I just installed (using pip) the python 'requests' module.

Eclipse is giving me an error warning on the 'import requests' line, saying that it is an unresolved import, but I've run it it imports just fine. (But the error message won't go away).

Its really bugging me, and I can't right-click and delete the error either. (The option is gray).

Is there any way to fix this? (Even if it involves manually removing the error?)

I know that there is a similar problem here:
[Eclipse Pydev - Misdiplayed Import Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18301970/eclipse-pydev-misdiplayed-import-error?rq=1)

but the answer to that was that PyDev had a bug specifically with PIL, so that is why I'm asking a different question.

Comment: When i was working with Eclipse and PyDev i used to get those weird import errors, and i've never been able to remove them. After a while i get used to it and then i switched to SublimeText

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, PyDev is a little buggy... When it happens, I usually right-click on the folder containing the file  in the PyDev Package Explorer, then "PyDev->remove error markers". And then re-run code analysis.

If it still doesn't work, try removing and adding again the directory to your `requests` module to the PyDev Path. As I said, PyDev is a little buggy...

Answer (score 0):

You should manually configure properties of you PyDev project.

Right click on your project name, select **PyDev - PYTHONPATH**, then in External Libraries tab press **Add source folder** and choose the root directory of your library.